# How much money do Lucky trait and Wealthy Tree yield?

Tags: pokemon-rumble-world

How much money does *Lucky++* and similar traits yield?
I've tried only with *Lucky+* trait but I can't understand the actual benefit.

And what about *money boosting moves*? And *Wealthy Tree*? Do they stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *Lucky* trait: plus 1 coin
  *Lucky+* trait: plus 2 coins
  *Lucky++* trait: plus 3 coins
- All pokémon bonus level: plus 1 coin
- Defeat a Pokemon using a money boosting move (*Pluck, Bug Bite, Payday, Thief, Knock Off, Covet*): occasionally plus 1 coin
- Each *Wealthy Tree* upgrade: +20% worth

Example:
Mii's gold coin reward at end of stage starts at 10, and goes 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, and 30 with the level 10 Wealthy Tree.
Small coins have a base value of 1, as your Wealthy Tree levels up, they will sometimes be worth 1 or 2, or 2 or 3 depending on your level.

These effects **all stack**, so if you have a *Lucky++* Pokémon using a *money boosting move*, on an all pokémon bonus level, you'll get maybe 5.5 coins per pokémon defeated (excluding captures).
At *level 10 Wealthy Tree* that's basically 15 pokécoin per Pokémon at a minimum, depends if they drop any larger or gold coins.

If you keep a combo going, every 10th combo drops extra coins, and every 50th combo seems to drop especially more coins.

Source [Gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/141816-pokemon-rumble-world/71750054).